# first node of stack defaulting - c

Tags: c, memory, struct, linked-list, stack

```
typedef struct node {
    double value;
    struct node *prev;
} node_t;
```

In main:

```
if(fgets(str, MAX_LENGTH, stdin)) {
    char *token;
    token = strtok(str, " ");
    while(token != NULL) {
        if(strtod(token, NULL) != 0) { //Issue here
            push(&stack, new_node(strtod(token, NULL)));
        }
......
```

For a test case, If my input is "1 2" then the first time I push a node onto the stack, node_t.prev = NULL (as desired) and the value is 1 (as desired). My second time through the loop, the first node in the stack defaults (prev = NULL, and value = 0). This occurs in the if statement (see commented above).

Why is my first node defaulting?

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++?

Answer (score 0):

When using `strtod()` within a loop you have to 'get the first token separately ', try this...

```
    token = strtod(token, " ");//get first token and do some test cases with it...
    while(token != NULL) {
    if(strtod(token, NULL) != 0) {
        push(&stack, new_node(strtod(token, NULL)));
    }
```

Try this, hopefully it works and that was your issue..

Comment: token is a string - token = strtod(token, " ") gives an error due to incompatible types

Comment: @Koverman47 Sorry that was meant as an example... have it be the first value you are reading in...